# Typescript compiling not shows errors on Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, tsc

I am working on Angular 2 application in Windows. For this moment everything was ok, till I try to run app on CentOS. I was confused when trying to compiling typescript on Linux gave me errors. Both systems have the same node and npm versions:

- npm v3.10.7
- node v4.5.0

I find out, that some errors ocurred, beacuse on Linux after "npm install" I have to run "npm run postinstall" manually. Rest of errors are easy to clean up by code changing.

Why "npm run tsc" does not throw errors on Windows?

"npm run tsc" output on CentOS

```
> my-app@1.0.0 tsc /root/MyApp/app
> tsc

app/main-panel/main-info.component.ts(22,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/main-panel/minor-info.component.ts(23,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/main-panel/data.component.ts(23,12): error TS7006: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/data.service.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/rx'.

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "tsc"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-app@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/MyApp/app/npm-debug.log
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"watch-less -d ./less -r ./css -e .css\" \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "watch": "concurrently \"watch-less -d ./less -r ./css -e .css\" \"tsc -w\"",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "watch-less": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: There are a few issues, but I see `Cannot find module 'rxjs/rx'`. Try just `import 'rxjs'`

Comment: For this issue works changing 'rxjs/rx' to 'rxjs/Rx', but the question was why I don't see this fails on Windows?

Comment: Same problem here. Any workaround if not solution? Thx for sharing.

Comment: As Linux is case sensitive, it found errors which was not discovered on Windows system. To catch errors on Windows we have start using tslint https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint

Comment: have you got any updates?